# Network exposure function in 5G core network

Tags: network, networking, network-core, network-access, network-discovery

I want  to integrate Network exposure function(NEF) to another core network functions . Is their any one  help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer support for the equipment you use will have specific information on how to do that on the equipment you use. It will also be unique to the network environment you manage and the services you want to expose for your users. Work with the manufacturer support and your internal staff to design the features/services and expose them via the systems you have.